# Как открыть sepolicy?

Tags: c++, selinux

Пробую:

```
#include <sepol/policydb.h>
#include <sepol/policydb/policydb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    sepol_policydb_t * pol;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sepolicy", "rb");
    sepol_policydb_read(pol, *fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт:

```
run.cpp:9:30: error: cannot convert ‘FILE’ to ‘sepol_policy_file_t*’ {aka ‘sepol_policy_file*’}
    9 |     sepol_policydb_read(pol, *fp);
      |                              ^~~
      |                              |
      |                              FILE
In file included from run.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sepol/policydb.h:113:76: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int sepol_policydb_read(sepol_policydb_t*, sepol_policy_file_t*)’
  113 | extern int sepol_policydb_read(sepol_policydb_t * p, sepol_policy_file_t * pf);
      |                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

Но че делать-то? Как правильно открыть sepolicy для функции `sepol_policydb_read()`? Никакой документации и пояснений нету нигде... Че за `sepоl_policy_file_t`, что он должен из себя представлять, я вообще не понимаю...

Comment: `Никакой документации и пояснений нету нигде...` И поэтому вы решили передавать случайные аргументы в случайные функции? `Но че делать-то?` 1) Не тратить своё время на недокументированный код, 2) Открывать исходники и долго и упорно их изучать.

Comment: угу, как мне с SELinux работать программно? Даже по python-selinux толком нету документации. Есть что-то худое по libselinux на сайте selinuxproject.org, но вот по libsepol, который мне нужен, нету вообще ничего. Вообще. А мне и python не нужен, мне C++ надо...

Comment: wololo, и да, функцию `sepol_policydb_read` я взял из policydb.h из исходников libsepol. А вот определить, что за аргументы нужны данной функции, я вообще не понял - я себе уже мозг сломал с `typedef`-ами и `datum`-ами в коде...

Comment: я прочёл в хедере как установить файловый указатель. `/*
 * Set the policy file to represent a FILE.
 * Subsequent operations using the policy file will read and write
 * to the FILE.
 */
extern void sepol_policy_file_set_fp(sepol_policy_file_t * pf, FILE * fp);` [github policydb.h](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/master/libsepol/include/sepol/policydb.h)

Comment: `/* Create and free memory associated with a policydb. */
extern int sepol_policydb_create(sepol_policydb_t ** p);` - сначала нужно структуру  создать.

Comment: `sepol_policydb_read(pol,` * `fp);` зачем звёздочку поставили?